# Passing a variable through a function when passing to a function

Tags: php

I'm not really sure what this is called or how to search for it so hopefully this hasn't been asked too many times before.

Is it possible to pass a variable to a function inside the function variable thing... I know that doesn't make sense, so here is an example:

```
sendContact('Firstname Lastname', $email, $address);

function sendContact(splitWord($name), $email, $address) {
    //code here
    print_r($name);
    //result array[0] = 'Firstname';
    //result array[1] = 'Lastname';
}

function splitWord($name) {
    //code here to split words
    return $result
}
```

All I'm looking for is the `sendContact(splitWord())` part. Is there a way to do that as that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: nope, but you can just call splitWord() inside of sendContact()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Don't put the function call in the definition, put it in the execution like so:

```
function sendContact( $name, $email ) {

}
function splitWord( $name ) {
  return $result;
}

sendContact( splitWord( $name ) );
```

Comment: Of course.. Wow, I can't believe this didn't cross my mind. It must be that time of day.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove some job from you?

```
sendContact('Firstname Lastname', $email, $address);

function sendContact($name, $email, $address) {
    $name = splitWord($name); // put inside to not duplicate for each call

    //code here

    print_r($name);

    //result array[0] = 'Firstname';
    //result array[1] = 'Lastname';
}

function splitWord($name) {
    //code here to split words
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could call your other function during the call for your main.. See an example:

```
function sendContact($name, $email, $address) {
    //code here
    print_r($name);
    //result array[0] = 'Firstname';
    //result array[1] = 'Lastname';
}

function splitWord($name) {
    //code here to split words
    return explode (" ",$name); // Different, but made to prduce an array to show that it works
}

sendContact(splitWord('Firstname Lastname'), $email, $address);
```

I have called the `splitWord()` function during the same time as i'm calling the `sendContact();` function

Answer (score 0):

If you are 'real programmer', it's bad practice writing code like that. You should use OOP approach, if there are lots of functions involved inside a function.

```
class Email
{

    function splitWord($name)
    {
         // the jobs of split
    }

    function sendContact($name, $email, $address)
    {
         $receiver = $this->split($name);
         mail($receiver, $email, $address);
    }
}
```

Comment: "real programmer" not puting objects everywhere. OOP is good when it needed, not forced. "OOP just for OOP" is not good.

Comment: Those were just examples. The `splitWord` function is not specific only to the `sendContact` function. I just put them there to give context to what I was trying to achieve. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

Not really. The most straightforward solution might be a simple wrapper function:

```
function sendAndSplitContact($name, $email, $address) {
  return sendContact(splitWord($name), $email, $address);
}
```